# Missing fields when rendering lotus notes document to RTF,DXL with Java API

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I'm attempting to render a notes document to RTF, then DXL using the Java API. Once I have the DXL, I'm converting it to HTML with an XSL stylesheet. My goal is to produce an HTML document that displays as close as possible to the document rendering in the notes client.

However, computed fields are missing from the rendered RTF and DXL.

Here is the code used to generate the DXL:

```
private String renderDocumentToDxl(lotus.domino.Document lotusDocument)
        throws Exception {
    Database db = getDatabase();
    lotus.domino.Document tmp = db.createDocument();

    RichTextItem rti = tmp.createRichTextItem("Body");
    lotusDocument.computeWithForm(true, false);
    lotusDocument.save();
    lotusDocument.renderToRTItem(rti);

    DxlExporter dxlExporter = getSession().createDxlExporter();
    dxlExporter.setOutputDOCTYPE(false);
    dxlExporter.setConvertNotesBitmapsToGIF(true);
    return dxlExporter.exportDxl(tmp);
}
```

Fields added to the document by the call to `computeWithForm` are not present in the generated DXL.

Is there any way to get the computed fields into the generated DXL with the Java API? Or is there a better way to generate an HTML representation of a notes document using the domino Java API?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear on your objective. There are two possibilities:

1) You want the items from lotusDocument to exist in tmp, and to be exported as actual  tag data in the DXL.  Your code does not do this.

2) You want the *values* of the non-hidden Items from lotusDocument to exist as text within the rich text Body item in tmp, and you want those values to be included within the DXL that is exported from tmp - as text within the  tag for the Body item.  This should be what your code is doing.

If you expected the former, then that's not what renderToRTItem does.  What it does is the latter. I.e., it gives you a snapshot of the *values* of the items in lotusDocument - but if and only if they would be displayed to a user who opens the document. You do not get the items themselves, and they won't appear separately in the DXL. If that's all you expected, and it's not happening, then there's something else going wrong and you haven't given enough infornmation here to figure it out.

If you wanted the former, i.e., the actual items from lotusDocument to exist as separate  tag elements within the DXL exported from tmp, then you should be using

`lotusDocument.copyAllItems(tmp,true);`,

or sequences of

`Item tmpItem = lotusDocument.getFirstItem(itemName); 
 tmp.copyItem(tmpItem,"");`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My end goal is to produce an HTML document containing a rendering that matches what is shown in the notes client. I have a XSL stylesheet that converts the DXL to HTML.

Comment: Okay.  Then I think that means you expect the values of the computed fields to be text  within the DXL for the Body item.  The only thing I can think of that would prevent that is hide-when checkbook settings or formulas on the paragraphs containing the computed fields. Do you have any plain text in the same paragraphs,  and does it appear in the DXL as expected?

Comment: In the DXL, the paragraphs are present but entirely empty. The paragraphs use hide/when lotus script formulas. These same documents are also rendered using the C API function `CompoundTextAddRenderedNote`, which does include the computed text tiems.

Comment: What are the hide-when formulas? Sounds like something about them is not working right in the context of your java code. And what, by the way, is that context? Is this agent code running on the server? Standalone code running on a client? Other?

Comment: This is standalone Java running on a host without the lotus notes client, connecting via DIIOP.

Comment: Okay... Here's a suggestion. Add a new paragraph, not hidden. Add a computed field to that paragraph. Take the hide-when formula for one of the missing fields and copy it into the field formula (not the hide-when) for the new computed field. Modify the last line of the copied formula to surround it with @If( formulaLineGoesHere; "***true"; "***false");  Then run your code and see what you get. I'm guessing you get "***true". Once confirmed, we can turn attention to why that's happening.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I added the field as you specified. It shows up as "***true" in the lotus notes client however does not show up when generating the document using the remote Java API.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the HTML representation of a RichText field with the URL

```
http://server/db.nsf/view/docunid/RichTextFieldname?OpenField
```

So, save your `tmp` document, get the docunid and read the result via http from URL

```
http://server/db.nsf/0/tmpdocunid/Body?OpenField
```

You don't need to call `lotusDocument.computeWithForm` as `lotusDocument.renderToRTItem` does execute form's input translation and validation formulas already.
Be aware that for both methods form's LotusScript code won't be executed - just in case your fields gets calculated this way.

In case you can use XPages this would be an alternative: http://linqed.eu/2014/07/11/getting-html-from-any-richtext-item/

Comment: This runs outside of the notes client and I don't believe url based access is enabled on our environment.
Is there documentation stating that the LotusScript code will not be executed? It certainly seems to be the case that it is not executed, however LotusScript does appear to be executed by the equivalent C API function `CompoundTextAddRenderedNote`.

Comment: Yes, in documentation for `computeWithForm` http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_COMPUTEWITHFORM_METHOD.html?lang=en says "Validates a document by executing the default value, translation, and validation **formulas**, if any are defined in the document form." Similar for `renderToRTItem`: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_RENDERTORTITEM_METHOD.html?lang=en

Comment: For using URL the kind of client is not important. The server has to run the http task and some security settings have to be set. Just try it...